# Apache2 redirect all sub-directories to index.html of main directory?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache2, proxy, ubuntu

I want to put an .htaccess file in a directory of my website. For this purpose in:

```
www.mysite.com/dir/
```

Then I want anything after `/dir/` to direct to `/dir/index.html` but still display the original URL in the browser.
So for example:

```
www.mysite.com/dir/foo/bar -> www.mysite/dir/index.html
```

So in essence I want the browser to go to `index.html` but display the original URL
Could this be done with a reverse proxy?

Comment: You could just URL Rewrite in your Htacces file: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ alternatively if you are using Cpanel you can just do this in your redirection settings.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for:
RewriteRule ^dir/.*$ index.html [NC,L] 

Sorry, I'm new at this. Just see if that helps.

Comment: @Sam that won't work because I want the URL in the browser to stay the same but the browser to display content from index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam's second comment was pretty close. This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^dir/(.*)   dir/index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: But then won't that change the URL displayed in the browser to index.html? I wan't it to display the same URL, the one before the redirect

Comment: Nope. It's not doing a redirect. That would look like: RewriteRule ^dir/(.*)  dir/index.html [R=301,L] - The R=301 is a 301 Redirect.

Comment: Thank you so much! Once I put a RewriteEngine On statement before that it worked perfectly!

Comment: @EricBrandel I tried to put this line in the .htaccess file in my site folder's dir, it still get 404 not found issue (because I am doing prettify url with one page app). Any solution?